# C++ - WINAPI - Object-oriented approach to closing a window

Tags: c++, winapi, window

While trying to create a nice wrapper around Win32 specific GUI components, I eventually ran into a problem. The problem is that I'm unable to close the application after the windows I created no longer exist.

My API works like this:

```
/// ----------------------------
/// @author     God
/// @project    Helixirr Widgets
/// ----------------------------
#include <helixirrwidgets/HelixirrWidgets.hpp>

int main(void){
    HelixirrWidgets::Window __windows[2] = {HelixirrWidgets::Window("Big Window"), HelixirrWidgets::Window()};

    __windows[0].position(200, 200);
    __windows[0].size(800, 600);
    __windows[0].visible(true);
    __windows[0].save_changes();

    __windows[1].name("Tiny Window");
    __windows[1].position(10, 100);
    __windows[1].size(400, 200);
    __windows[1].visible(true);
    __windows[1].save_changes();

    while(__windows[0].active() || __windows[1].active()){
        if(__windows[0].visible()){
            __windows[0].show();
        }
        if(__windows[1].visible()){
            __windows[1].show();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In method of **HelixirrWidgets::Window** called "active", which is declared like this

```
inline bool active(void) const noexcept;
```

I can check, whether my window is active or not.

This method basically return a const reference to a boolean member variable of an instance. This member variable is modified in "show"-method of the same class. Here's the definition:

```
void Window::show(void){
    if(GetMessage(&_m_opHelper->message, _m_opHelper->handle_window, 0, 0)){
        if(_m_opHelper->message.message == WM_CLOSE){
            _m_bActive = false;
            return;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&_m_opHelper->message);
        DispatchMessage(&_m_opHelper->message);

        ShowWindow(_m_opHelper->handle_window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        UpdateWindow(_m_opHelper->handle_window);

        _m_bActive = true;
        return;
    }
    _m_bActive = false;
}
```

Do note I use pimpl-idiom to hide platform-specific structures ("_m_opHelper" is pointer to implementation).

It may look like it works, but it doesn't and I can't understand why. It all comes down to a simple question: *how can I close my window implemented using WINAPI specific functions and structures to be closed appropriately by a user of my application*?

Comment: Identifiers with double underscores or  an underscore followed by a capitalized letter are reserved by the implementation (i.e. the compiler and library). Don't use them. Your compiler might summon nasal demons. Not even God can withstand their evil powers.

Comment: One would think God has no difficulty closing an application.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice, but I'd like to distinguish local variables from all other variables present in my code this way. I'm aware of the fact that underscoring may give unexpected results if you don't know you're using preprocessor definition or something, but so far, I have never encountered a problem with this approach.

Comment: @Floris Velleman: God helps me to code, you know. It would be wrong to take ownership of all the good he's done, if you know what I mean. :-)

Comment: So, any ideas how to help out? We got kinda off topic here, you know?

Comment: Your question is not clear: `how can I close my window ... to be closed appropriately by a user`. Please write exactly what you want to do.

Comment: How about if you start each function with a namespace named `local`, so that would be `local::windows[0].position ...`? As far as closing the window goes, you normally do it with PostQuitMessage. After that, your message loop will exit (assuming you've written it sort of close to correctly).

Comment: You are doing this fundamentally wrong, a message loop is a thread property, not a window property.  If you want to reinvent this wheel then at least look at the way the many other GUI class libraries do it.

Comment: @Hans Passant: No multi-threading support yet, but I try to keep that in mind. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the cause of the issue is related to the fact `WM_CLOSE` simply is not last message `HWND` gets. Messages like `WM_DESTROY`, `WM_NCDESTROY` and possibly more (depending on the particlar window and its state) will come after `WM_CLOSE`, leading to the assignment `_m_bActive = TRUE`.

I.e. the window becomes inactive for very short time, and (likely) they will never be inactive at the same time, causing an endless loop in `main()`.

Comment: Your suggestions helped me to find a solution: PostQuitMessage(0) was in wrong location.